# 'Zend_Exception' -> 'Registry is already initialized'

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

Here is my complete error:

> Strict Standards: Accessing static property
>   Bootstrap::$frontController as non static in
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php
>   on line 145
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message
>   'Registry is already initialized' in
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/Zend/Registry.php:70 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/application/Bootstrap.php(217):
>   Zend_Registry::setInstance(Object(Zend_Registry)) #1
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/application/Bootstrap.php(56):
>   Bootstrap->_initSetupRegistry() #2
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669):
>   Bootstrap->_initPrepare() #3
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('prepare')
>   4
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #5
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/Zend/Application.php(355):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #6 in
>   /Users/panda/Dropbox/www/_playground/myApp/Zend/Registry.php on line
>   70

Here is the function from my bootstrap

```
/*
* Zend_Registry get's born here so it can be accesed
*/
protected function _initSetupRegistry()
{

    self::$registry = new Zend_Registry(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    Zend_Registry::setInstance(self::$registry);

}
```

If you need more code, please let me know, I will like some tips for finding the problem, or if someone knows the exact problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with this method?

If you just want an instance of the registry use `Zend_Registry::getInstance()`. You shouldn't be constructing it (I'm not sure why they used a singleton pattern but didn't make __construct private).

If you really want to replace an instance of Zend_Registry call `Zend_Registry::_unsetInstance()` first.

If you just want to set the static $registry variable so you can reference it later try:

```
self::$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance(); 
self::$registry->set('configuration', 'myconfig');
```

But I'm not sure this is necessary because you can access `Zend_Registry::getInstance()` from any scope. So the above is the same as:

```
Zend_Registry::getInstance()->set('configuration', 'myconfig');
```

Which you can call anywhere.

Comment: self::$registry = new Zend_Registry(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
        Zend_Registry::getInstance(self::$registry); like this doesn't set the registry data

Comment: getInstance() doesn't set anything.. it doesn't take any params. Look at the class.

Comment: Than how should I use it, because I'm using this in my class to set values like `self::$registry->configuration = 'my config';`

Comment: `self::$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance(); self::$registry->set('configuration', 'myconfig');`

Comment: You the best, edit the answer and paste that in so I can accept it